# remove : prolog

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

I am trying to compile csp.pl from "Computational Intelligence book" which solves the constraint satisfaction problem. I want to use this as a base to solve crossword puzzle generator.

But when I try to run the code it gives

```
 Existence error in user:remove/3
! procedure user:remove/3 does not exist
! goal:  user:remove([1,2,3,4],3,_127)
| ?- :-
```

I think remove is not a built-in predicate

```
% select(E,L,L1) selects the first element of
% L that matches E, with L1 being the remaining
% elements.
select(D,Doms,ODoms) :-
   remove(D,Doms,ODoms), !.

% choose(E,L,L1) chooses an element of
% L that matches E, with L1 being the remaining
% elements.
choose(D,Doms,ODoms) :-
   remove(D,Doms,ODoms).
```

This is the part of the code... Can anyone please help me fix this issue...
Code should execute since in the textbook its claimed to hv run on some programs..

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `remove` is part of any Prolog library -- certainly not SWI Prolog. The list library is [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29).

There is a predicate `delete` which does the same thing that code uses `remove` for. So just find-and-replace and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Load the [`lists` library](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.7.1/html/sicstus_19.html#SEC193) using

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
```

This gives you access to the `lists:select/3` predicate, which does what your `choose/3` should do. `lists:delete/3` is almost your `remove/3`, except with the arguments in a different order.